# Only save transformed parameters in PyMC3

Tags: python, bayesian, pymc3, mcmc

I want to shift my variables in PyMC3. I'm currently just using [deterministic transforms](https://docs.pymc.io/notebooks/api_quickstart#Deterministic-transforms), but when I perform the inference, it saves both the original samples and the shifted samples (which is expected behavior).

Example code:

```py
import pymc3 as pm

x_lower = -3

with pm.Model():
    x = pm.Gamma('x', alpha=2., beta=1.5)
    x_shift = pm.Deterministic("x_shift", x + x_lower)
    trace = pm.sample(1000, tune=1000)
trace.remove_values("x")  # my current solution

tp = pm.traceplot(trace)
# other analysis...
```

Now `trace` stores all `x` samples and all `x_shift` samples, which is clearly a waste when the numbers of variables and samples increase. I can do `trace.remove_values("x")` before continuing with analysis, but I would prefer to simply not save`x` at all.

Another option is to not save `x_shift` at all, but I can't find how to add `x_lower` on to the samples after inference. So this isn't really a solution if I want to use the in-built analysis tools.

Can I save *only* the `x_shift` samples, and *not* the `x` samples, when I `sample`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify exactly what you want to save by setting the `trace` argument in the `pm.sample()` function, e.g.,

```
trace = pm.sample(1000, tune=1000, trace=[x_shift])
```

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone finds this...

I went for a still-unsatsifying solution: I'm not using `Deterministic` transformations any more. I still transform the variables, but don't save them. I just transform the saved (original) samples after sampling.

The above code now looks like this:

```
import pymc3 as pm

x_lower = -3

def f_x(x):
    return x + x_lower

with pm.Model():
    x = pm.Gamma('x', alpha=2., beta=1.5)
    x_shift = f_x(x)
    #keep = {"x": f_x}  # something like this for more variables
    trace = pm.sample(1000, tune=1000)
trace = {"x": f_x(trace["x"])}  # note this merges all chains
#trace = {varname: f(trace[varname]) for varname, f in keep.items()}

tp = pm.traceplot(trace)
# other analysis...
```

I think the `pm.traceplot(trace)` still works with `trace` in this form, but otherwise just import `arviz` and use it directly --- it does work with dicts like this.

Note: take care with more complicated transformations. e.g. you'll have to use `pm.math.exp` in the model, but `np.exp` in the post-sampling transformation.